# Possible to check if a particulor field exist or not in select query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to check if a particular field exist or not in sql select query

```
select c.uid,c.cust_id,c.cust_name,a.phone 
from customer c, address a 
where (c.uid = a.uid Or a.uid is null)
```

In some case address table does not include phone corresponding to c.uid, in that case it will make an error. Is it possible to avoid that

Comment: You mean that your result returns no rows? Handle it in the code where the result is used!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: @OlleR: and `plsql` which is Oracle's procedural language

Comment: Yes. But i need to avoid a.phone from my code and select remaining item. Is it possible to pass some null value if the row is not exist

Comment: Check the answer below. That should do the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are asking, but it sounds as if you want an outer join:

```
select c.uid,c.cust_id,c.cust_name,a.phone 
from customer c 
   left join address a on c.uid = a.uid
```